# Downgrading chrome from unstable to stable on Linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian

I have downgraded Google Chrome from unstable to stable recently (version 11 to 10) and I get an error message that the user profile is incompatible. How can I fix it?

Comment: They may use different file formats that are not backwards compatable.

Comment: Hi @new123456, I understand why I get this message, I just want to fix it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chrome user profile is located in ~/.config/google-chrome/Default.  Make a backup copy of the Default directory, then delete it.  Chrome should create a new Default profile when it starts.  Your bookmarks, cookies, etc. are in there so you may need to restore your bookmarks from your backup copy after Chrome creates the new Default profile directory.

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to cheat the system using Google sync.

You could take your current profile and enable Google sync (*you do have a Gmail account, don't you?*). This will hopefully act as a data translator, as it is completely probable that any sync-enabled version of Google Chrome will be able to access this information. Do this with your current build.

Then, downgrade, and set sync to your Gmail account, and Chrome will, in all infinite improbability, actually give you your settings back (which include things like bookmarks, preferences, themes, etc).